# I wish to pivot an SQL table but not sure if table is pivotable in manner i want

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple sql table with four columns The data types are

```
Athlete nvarchar(30)
Mydate  date
Mytime  varchar(8)
Session nvarchar(40)

Athlete   Mydate               Session       Mytime
Jerry     14/04/2009            200m         00:00:43
Jerry     14/04/2009            200m         00:00:44
Jerry     14/04/2009            200m         00:00:38
Jerry     14/04/2009            200m         00:00:40
Tom       14/04/2009            200m         00:00:45
Tom       14/04/2009            200m         00:00:48
Tom       14/04/2009            200m         00:00:40
Tom       14/04/2009            200m         00:00:47
Tom       14/04/2009            200m         00:00:48
```

Now what I want is to create a query that outputs as below

```
Athlete   Mydate       Session     Time1       Time2      Time3      Time4      Time5   Time6
Jerry     14/04/2009       200m   00:00:43    00:00:44   00:00:38   00:00:40
Tom       14/04/2009       200m   00:00:40    00:00:45   00:00:48   00:00:40      00:00:47
```

Any help most appreciated

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server? (not every RDBMS have a built-in "pivot" function). Please add the tag corresponding to your specific RDBMS

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: the `sql` tag refers to general SQL questions. Please be sure to add the tags corresponding to the *specific RDBMS* you are using (I've just done it for you, please be sure to do it next time ;-) )

Comment: Regarding to your question, how are the rows ordered? Is there an `id` field or something that allows to order the rows per athlete? If there's not, then times may be ordered randomly. Add a column with the number of row per athlete. SQL Server does have a `pivot` function. Use `max()` as an aggregate function in the pivot.

Comment: PIVOT or a CrossTab approach would probably help to solve the task (together with ROW_NUMBER, I guess). But either one would require a column to identify which time would belong to which column (Time1, Time2...). The data provided don't provide such a criteria...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables are inherently unordered, and you don't seem to have an ordering in mind.  Although you can use `pivot` for this, I often just approach a problem like this using conditional aggregation.  The key here is you need some number for the times.

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by athlete, mydate, session order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from sometable t
     )
select athlete, mydate, session,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then time end) as time1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then time end) as time2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then time end) as time3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then time end) as time4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then time end) as time5
from t
group by athlete, mydate, session;
```